# How can I print my 2D vector in a matrix form? C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have created a 2D vector that is populated by values in a text file. The values provided will always be N*N so my question is, how can I print out the vector of vectors in a matrix form, i.e. in a 3x3 grid.
My code so far is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Declaration
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("example.txt");
    int n;
    int x;
    myfile >> n;

    //Creation of 2D vector
    vector<vector<int> > grid;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        vector<int> temp;
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            while (myfile >> x){
                temp.push_back(x);
            }
        }
        grid.push_back(temp);
    }

    //Display the elements of the 2D vector

    for (int i=0; i<grid.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<grid[i].size(); j++){
            cout << "[" << grid[i][j] << "]";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I tried to add cout << "[" << grid[i][j] << "]"; to do this but this only outputs a single line of all the values, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I am sitting at a table with a pen in front of a piece of paper. I will draw what you tell me to. You tell me to draw a number sandwiched between `[ ]`. And another. And another. You never tell me to go to the next line. Why won't you tell me to go to the next line!?

Comment: Since we don't have access to `example.txt`, use this [template](https://godbolt.org/z/6Pfv8m) and put whatever is in `example.txt` inside the place marked "_replace this space with the content of your file_". That'd make it possible for others to run your program with the same data.

Answer (score 1):

Put a new line after every loop through `i`?

```
for (int i=0; i<grid.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<grid[i].size(); j++) {
        cout << "[" << grid[i][j] << "]";
    }
    // Add a new line after every row
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that was one of my thoughts too however it doesn't seem to change anything other than a newline be added after the whole "[2][3][1][..."

Comment: If you put that newline exactly where @BTown did, and you don't get a newline until the end of the whole sequence, that means your data is only one row. Run your debugger (actually run it) and inspect the values in your vectors. How many vectors are in your main vector? If you only have one line, there should only be one.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I follow as I'm very new to C++. I did add in a line 'cout << j << endl;' after the other 'cout ...' and its lists the numbers 0-8, does that mean its only as 1 line as I would've expected it to go 0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2? (I also added an if statement 'if((j+1)%n == 0){ cout << endl; }' which gives me the desired effect, but I'm worried that the vector might not be how I planned it to be since later I was planning on having a vector location [i][j] and then doing a check for the vector locations it "touches" i.e. [i-1][j], [i+1][j], [i][j-1] and [i][j+1]

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to figure it out with the help of @John as he had mentioned the number of vectors I had. I didn't consider that I may have just populated the first vector (j=0) with the values rather than having 3 in j=0,1,2.
In the end I used the code:

```
for (int i=0; i<grid.size(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<grid[i].size(); j++){
        cout << "[" << grid[i][j] << "] ";
        if((j+1)%n == 0){
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

This displayed it as I had requested but I had the underlying problem as they were all in 1 sub-vector. This was simply fixed by changing the:

```
while (myfile >> x) { ... }
```

To:

```
if (myfile >> x) { ... }
```

Hope this can help some of you!